# Best HTML5 Audio/Video Player for my website?

Tags: php, jquery, html

I want to know the best html5 audio/video for my website. I can find few players when I google it, but not sure which one to use. It should be working in all the browsers/devices with automatic Flash fallback

Did some research and found https://www.mediaelementjs.com/ is a very nice HTML5 player.

Comment: Check this neat [website](http://www.google.com).

Comment: I already used google, but it lists lots of players. That's the reason why I posted it.

Comment: It all depends on what you regard as 'the best'.  I'd suggest spending some time researching what is available and coming to your own conclusion.

Comment: @VijayJoseph yes, because you got your own ideas of whats the best, like me say windows is the best but you will say that linux is the best

Answer (score 5):

I think the best HTML5 videoplayer is

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="controls">
  <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
  <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">
  Your browser doesn't support HTML5 Video
</video>
```

and audioplayer is

```
<audio controls="controls">
  <source src="horse.ogg" type="audio/ogg">
  <source src="horse.mp3" type="audio/mpeg">
  Your browser doesn't support HTML5 Audio
</audio>
```

its awesome it works in all html5 browsers and its just awesome

Comment: the browser must support audio and video tags.it is better to select standalone player like jw-player

Answer (score 2):

Sounds like you are looking for [jwPlayer](http://www.longtailvideo.com/players)